Как сделать так чтобы бот мог читать сообщения в канале. Aiogram 3+
У меня есть каналл в который я отпраляю сообщения, мне надо чтоб бот копировал сообщения из каналла в чат
from aiogram import Router, Bot, F
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command

router = Router()


words = ["Выполнено✅: Паспорт загружен", "Замок: гость успешно открыл замок впервые с помощью кода"]

@router.message(Command("id"))
async def get_id(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"Чат ид: {message.chat.id}")
    await message.answer(f"Твой ид: {message.from_user.id}")


@router.message()
async def check_message(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    print("jhk")
    text = message.text
    for word in words:
        if word.lower() in text.lower():
            await bot.send_message(chat_id="-1002236340076", text=message.text)

вот код который копирует сообщения из чата и отправляет в чат, но с каналлом это не работает


У Вас есть канал, чтоб копировать из канала нужен user-bot;

Если посты публикуете не программно (ручками),
то для user-bot(a) лучше использовать вспомогательный аккаунт;

В одном скрипте параллельно запускаете обычного bot(a) и user-bot(a).
(в качестве примера посмотрите мой ответ);

Пропишите логику взаимодействия между user-bot(ом) и bot(ом);

Если же публикуете программно, то взаимодействуйте с bot(ом) программно,
а не через сервер телеграм...


